# FSEEK error while running Matlab function

Tags: matlab

I got this error while running a function in Matlab

"Error using fseek Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier."

May I know what is the possible causes of this error? I am very new to Matlab. Please help me. Thanks a lot

I am sorry if I should not post the overall function. But I am afraid the information I gave is not enough. The overall command of the function is:

```
function  gau_hmm_init_train(traininglist_filename,model_filename,MODEL_NO,STATE_NO, dim )
if nargin == 0
    traininglist_filename='training_list.mat' ;
    model_filename='models.mat';
    MODEL_NO=11;
    STATE_NO=4;
    dim=12;
end
MIN_SELF_TRANSITION_COUNT=0;
load(traininglist_filename,'list');
% allocate mean, var vectors, transition prob. for the of models
mean_vec_i_m=zeros(dim,STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
var_vec_i_m=zeros(dim,STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
A_i_m=zeros(STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
vector_sums_i_m=zeros(dim,STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
var_vec_sums_i_m=zeros(dim,STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
fr_no_i_m=zeros(STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
self_tr_fr_no_i_m=zeros(STATE_NO,MODEL_NO);
utterance_no=size(list,1);
total_fr_no=0;
for k=1:utterance_no
    filename=list{k,2};
    m=list{k,1}; % word ID
    fid=fopen(filename,'r');
    fseek(fid, 12, 'bof'); % skip the 12-byte HTK header
    %fopen(fid, 12, 'bof'); % skip the 12-byte HTK header
    c=fread(fid,'float','b');
    fclose(fid);
    fr_no=length(c)/dim;
    total_fr_no=total_fr_no+fr_no;
    c=reshape(c,dim,fr_no);

    for i=1:STATE_NO
        begin_fr=round(  fr_no*(i-1) /STATE_NO)+1;
        end_fr=round( fr_no*i /STATE_NO);
        seg_length=end_fr-begin_fr+1;
        vector_sums_i_m(:,i,m) = vector_sums_i_m(:,i,m) + sum(c(:,begin_fr:end_fr),2);
        var_vec_sums_i_m(:,i,m) = var_vec_sums_i_m(:,i,m) +  sum( c(:,begin_fr:end_fr).*c(:,begin_fr:end_fr) , 2);
        fr_no_i_m(i,m)=fr_no_i_m(i,m)+seg_length;
        self_tr_fr_no_i_m(i,m)= self_tr_fr_no_i_m(i,m) + seg_length-1;
    end %for s=1:STATE_NO
end % for k=1:utterance_no
for m=1:MODEL_NO
    for i=1:STATE_NO
        mean_vec_i_m(:,i,m) = vector_sums_i_m(:,i,m) / fr_no_i_m(i,m);
        var_vec_i_m(:,i,m) = var_vec_sums_i_m(:,i,m) / fr_no_i_m(i,m);
        A_i_m(i,m)=(self_tr_fr_no_i_m(i,m)+MIN_SELF_TRANSITION_COUNT)/(fr_no_i_m(i,m)+2*MIN_SELF_TRANSITION_COUNT);
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                   tying of cov. matrices
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
overall_var_vec=sum(sum(var_vec_sums_i_m(:,:,:),3 ),2)/sum(sum(fr_no_i_m,2 ),1);
for m=1:MODEL_NO
    for i=1:STATE_NO
        var_vec_i_m(:,i,m)=overall_var_vec;
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            end of cov. matrices tying
save(model_filename, 'mean_vec_i_m', 'var_vec_i_m', 'A_i_m');
fprintf('init. train complete \n');***
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the line `fid=fopen(filename, 'r')`. This filename comes from the `list` variable which is loaded from the file `traininglist_filename`, so you should check that these files exist. If you're passing it a `traininglist_filename` you should load this file in MATLAB and look at the contents of list; otherwise it will load the default `'training_list.mat'`, so you should look in there to make sure all the filenames are valid. Perhaps you're missing a file?

Comment: Thanks a lot Wakjah for the answer. May I ask, if the dataset given is in .zip should I extract it first? I am sorry again if this question sounds stupid. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am sorry, May be I should make the clearer question by posting the command. 
list_filename='training_list.mat';
dir1='mfcc_e_d_a/isolated_digits_ti_train_endpt';
dir2={'MAN','WOMAN'};
dir3={{'AE','AJ','AL','AW','BD','CB','CF','CR','DL','DN','EH','EL','FC','FD','} ,
      
is that mean I should have 3 folders for dir1 , dir2 and dir3? thanks

Answer (score -1):

To continue the reply by @Wakjah, the `training_list.mat` file is missing from the reference path by the code you are using because it is automatically created at MATLAB default path. Therefore, just change the path at the 'Current Folder' to where you had open your current code and it should work.

Comment: While this is an answer, could you expand on it at all? Read here for more information on how to give good answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer